# I am trying to get the one line generator expression to do nothing if the condition is not True

Tags: python, for-loop, generator, one-liner

Here is my code, I was trying to subtract two lists using a generator expression but I couldn't get the generator expression to do nothing is if the condition is not met.

```py
ab=[1,2,2,3,4,5]
b=[3,4,5]
[ a if a in list(set(ab)-set(b)) else (nothing) for a in ab]
```

I want the generator expression to return `[1,2,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this (list of items in `ab` that are not in `b`)

```
[x for x in ab if x not in b]
```